# Read value from Environment variables in Github inputs

Tags: terraform, yaml, github-actions, pipeline

I am setting up a Terraform pipeline in Github workflow.

Below is the initial set of code:

```
name: 'Github Workflow'
run-name: 'Terraform Plan-Apply'

on:
   workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:
      Configuration:
        description: 'Deployment Group'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
        - Applications
        - KeyVault
        - Synapse
        - Databricks
      Environment:  
        description: 'Environment'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
        - Dev
        - QA
        - Prod
      GithubRunner:
            description: 'Environment'
        required: True
        default: ${{ env.Runner }}
```

Under Settings in Github, I have created three environments Dev, QA and Prod. Each environment has a variable named 'Runner' which holds the runner information. I tried the above code and it is not fetching the details.
Output of the above code:
Its showing as ${{ env.Runner }} in the Workflow.

Is there a way to read the value from environment variable? like, fetch the value according to the environment selected?

Comment: You can't read from the env as an input. What you likely have to do is use job1 to read from the env and set outputs based on the variables. In job2 reference the outputs from job1 for `runs-on:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the environment you want to use within the job.

You can specify an environment for each job in your workflow. To do so, add a `jobs.<job_id>.environment` key followed by the name of the environment.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment

Only then shall the environment variables defined for that environment be available.

I have fixed your workflow file.

```yaml
name: 'Github Workflow'
run-name: 'Terraform Plan-Apply'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Configuration:
        description: 'Deployment Group'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
          - Applications
          - KeyVault
          - Synapse
          - Databricks
      Environment:  
        description: 'Environment'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
          - Dev
          - QA
          - Prod

jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ${{ vars.Runner }}
    environment: ${{ inputs.Environment }}
```

Comment: under jobs, runs-on will be taking the github runner value, not ubuntu latest. So here also we are looking for a logic to read from the environment variable

Comment: @Asterix I have updated my answer. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Robin Thomas, you first specify the targeted environment in the <jobs.<job_id>.environment key followed by the name of the environment.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment

Then your environments variables will be accessible under ${{ vars.VARNAME }}.

Here is your file:

```
name: 'Github Workflow'
run-name: 'Terraform Plan-Apply'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Configuration:
        description: 'Deployment Group'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
          - Applications
          - KeyVault
          - Synapse
          - Databricks
      Environment:  
        description: 'Environment'
        required: True
        type: choice
        options:
          - Dev
          - QA
          - Prod

jobs:
  deployment:
    runs-on: ${{ vars.Runner }}
    environment: ${{ inputs.Environment }}
```

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context for details of contexts where "vars" are accessible in a Github Actions file and an example which covers your issue.